# Get all time value according to its primary key

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql table like this:
[image]

I want to extract all time value from the table by ID and date using php. Thanks in advance.

I want the output to be like this:

```
01403003 2015-09-01 07:54 11:00 11:42 17:02 17:03
```

Comment: You'll have to be more specific.

Comment: What have you done so far? Where is your code?

Comment: How? through a select/where statement https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html - go through that, then come back when you've tried something and may have difficulty with your code; something that isn't included in your question.

Comment: I tried the select but all i can get are the minimum and the maximum values.

Comment: then use aggregate min/max/count functions, group by etc. again, show the code you tried it with.

Comment: i tried this $qry="select ID, ValidDate, ValidTime,Day,MIN(ValidTime) as Inn, MAX(ValidTime) as OutTime from temprec group by ID,ValidDate"; but some values are skipping  and some are not showing in the echo like the 11:00 of 01403003.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you looking for is group_concat.

*This function returns a string result with the concatenated non-NULL values from a group.*

So for your need you can do something like:

```
SELECT id, date, group_concat(valid_time) from TABLE_NAME group by id, date;
```

it will return result like:

```
01403003 2015-09-01 07:54, 11:00, 11:42, 17:02, 17:03
```

Comment: Thanks for so long that i searched google and asking you are the only one that understand what I want to accomplish. Thank you very much from this point I can move forward.

Answer (score 0):

I would SELECT all (*) the record FROM the TABLE and ORDER it BY ValidDate, ValidTime,, Hours;

From there the sky is the limit , gl hf

Comment: what epocx timestamp?

Comment: Sorry I am really new to php and mysql, how can I display the data the way I want it to be displayed?